# How to fix no response on browser window when trying to upload large files?

Tags: php, nginx, raspbian

I want to upload movies or large amount of videos that usually total more than 1 Gigabyte, the PHP Code already works for small files (under a gigabyte) and for small number of video ( 5 or less). But when I try to upload larger files a myriad of errors have happened, such as chrome resetting the window, the files not getting uploaded even thou the script finished, simply the browser turning white and the server not responding or simply saying error 504, Gateway Timeout.

I already configure my php.ini file to accept the amount of  files and the size of the files, the nginx server i use is also configured to accept file uploads, so i have no idea were these errors are coming from.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
     $Pass = $_POST["Pass"];
    if($Pass === "Master"){
        $Passok = 1;
        $uploadOk = 1;
        echo "Password Correct";
        echo nl2br("\n");
    }else{
        echo "Password Incorrect";
        echo nl2br("\n");
        exit;
    }

    if($Passok==1){
    nl2br("\n");
    echo "<br/>";

    $filecount= sizeof($_FILES["userfiles"]["name"]);
    echo "Number of files uploaded: ".$filecount;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Original Name of Files: ";
    echo "<br/>";
    for($x=0; $x < $filecount;$x++){
    echo $_FILES["userfiles"]["name"][$x];
    echo "<br/>";
    }

        #$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] = $FinalName;
        #$target_file = $target_dir.$FinalName;
    echo "Modified Name of Files:";
    for($x=0; $x < $filecount;$x++){
    #Naming change
    $target_dir = "../Mount/";
    $FileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_dir . basename($_FILES["userfiles"]["name"][$x]),PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $NameofFile=basename($_FILES["userfiles"]["name"][$x]);
    $filter1= filter_var($NameofFile,FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $finalfilter = preg_replace ('/[^\p{L},p{N}]/u', '', $filter1);
    $FinalName=$finalfilter.".".$FileType;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $FinalName;
    echo "<br/>";
    $_FILES["userfiles"]["name"][$x]=$FinalName;
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["userfiles"]["name"][$x]);
    #$FileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    #Naming change
    #Check if file Exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
    #Check File Size
    if ($_FILES["userfiles"]["size"][$x] > 9000000000){  
    echo "Sorry,file is too large, wont upload, max size is 9gigabites";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
#Upload
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfiles"]["tmp_name"][$x], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". $FinalName. " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
    }


    echo "<br/>";

    }






} #end of Pass if   


}

?>
```

usually works for most small files, but when files get larger it fails, I don't know why.

Comment: Check that nginx and PHP does not have a maximum post limit set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Nginx timeout and packet max body size in nginx.conf or the config file in /etc/nginx/sites-available (or sites-enabled)

```
proxy_connect_timeout       300; # (5 minutes)
proxy_send_timeout          300;
proxy_read_timeout          300;
send_timeout                300;
client_max_body_size      2048M; # (2 GB)
```

Then check configuration with `sudo nginx -t` and if ok, reload configuration with `sudo service nginx reload`

Comment: I also tried this, still get the 504 gateway timeout error'

Comment: Could you try to upload smaller files, trying to use incremental dimension, like 1 MB, 10 MB, 100 MB, 1GB, 2GB and check the max you could upload? 
Can you also check how much time elapses until you have the timeout error?

Comment: Okay, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

try updating the execution time and post size by adding this code in your php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 1800
max_input_time = -1
post_max_size = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
memory_limit = 256M
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but the nginx server still gives 504 Gateway timeout errors.

Comment: is it your local? You may dont have permissions to modify that.

Comment: It is my local, I manage the entire server so i can make any modifications i need.